# date format %d/%m%y in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, sqldatatypes

I will enshortened the proble for the sake of simplicity:

I'd want to import a file with the following data:

```
21/01/1896
03/04/1905
01/05/1906
04/08/1905
28/07/1904
01/11/1908
04/08/1904
03/01/1915
03/11/1903
27/11/1887
25/03/1903
25/05/1901
24/12/1889
01/01/1910

mysql> DESCRIBE Fechas;
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Fechas | date | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So I try to import the file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Fechas' INTO TABLE Fechas;
```

After import:

```
mysql> select * from Fechas limit 5;
+------------+
| Fechas     |
+------------+
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
+------------+
```

If a take a look at variables:

```
mysql> show variables like '%time%';
+----------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value             |
+----------------------------+-------------------+
| connect_timeout            | 10                |
| datetime_format            | %d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300               |
| flush_time                 | 0                 |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50                |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF               |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800             |
| lc_time_names              | es_AR             |
| long_query_time            | 10.000000         |
| net_read_timeout           | 30                |
| net_write_timeout          | 60                |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600              |
| slow_launch_time           | 2                 |
| system_time_zone           | ART               |
| table_lock_wait_timeout    | 50                |
| time_format                | %H:%i:%s          |
| time_zone                  | SYSTEM            |
| timed_mutexes              | OFF               |
| timestamp                  | 1395284423        |
| wait_timeout               | 28800             |
+----------------------------+-------------------+
```

When I perform a select  it outputs:

```
mysql> select * from Fechas limit 5;
+------------+
| Fechas     |
+------------+
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
| 0000-00-00 |
+------------+
```

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Am I doing something wrong? Why even setting the datetime_format it persists on showing in format %Y-%m-%d ? What have I to do to mysql shows the fields as the date format from the source file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try *answer by user3442944* from below. But still, what is the value for `show variables like '%date_format';`

Comment: date_format is useless either :(

Answer (score 2):

You can only change the format when you are displaying from the select query only.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fechas,'%d/%m/%Y') FROM Fechas
```

You can only store the date/time in the default format.
As for the datetime_format variable. It is unused. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datetime_format)

Comment: So, the only solution is editing the file to have %Y-%m-%d format, isn't? Your suggestion works but AFTER editing the file, otherwise it outputs each record as 00/00/0000 and only about this it has nothing to do with mysql localization hasn't it?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with mysql localization. From what i can remember, mysql localization only involved character sets, timezones, month names, etc.. and not the date format